# I use name data to result code,Sql update question

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
Update x1 a set a.dept_cd=(select distinct dept_cd from x2 b a.nm=b.nm)
```

It's my sql
Distinct make data unique, but  it result in an error message,

> row subquery returns more than one row

My data is string
So i use name to return `code(dept_cd)`
Can you help me?

Comment: it's oracle so i can't use update~from ...

Comment: you tagged the question as "MySQL" and you are commenting it as "it's Oracle". It cannot be both... which engine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If this query return that error, it means that you have more than one dept_cd where nm is equal to the one you are looking for.

The goal of distinct is to avoid having twice the same value of dept_cd.

If you need one the first one no matter what the value is, you can add `limit 0,1` ad the end of your subquery.

If the value you need is a specific one, you need to find a way to update your query to isolate it but without having the full context, we cannot help you on that.

Comment: Hello again, if this answer solved your issue, please validate it so that we know that we don't have to search for another solution (and if someone else is searching for a problem similar, he/she knows what to try :)). And if it's not solving your issue, please explain why (as much as you can :)) so that we can search for the next solution